# Remove Json row that contains a specific value

Tags: php, json

I've got an Json output with three values.

```
{"contacts":[{"id":"1","name":"one"},{"id":"2","name":"two"},{"id":"3","name":"three"}]}
```

And I would like to remove the row with the ID equal to 2, and output this:

```
 {"contacts":[{"id":"1","name":"one"},{"id":"3","name":"three"}]}
```

My code

```
$output = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
    $output[] = $row;
  }



    $json = json_encode(array(
    "contacts" => $output
));

    echo strip_tags($json);
```

How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: I tried to use unset, but unset only removes a specific value, and I would like to remove the full row. I have been searching for hours trying to find a solution, but I didn't find anything that could help me.

Comment: unset the entire row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the obvious:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if ($row['id'] != '2') { $output[] = $row; }
}
```

What you are doing is returning the array, but a filtered version of it.  So use `array_filter`:

```
$json = json_encode(array(
            'contacts' => array_filter(function($row) {
                 return $row['id'] != '2';
             }, $output)
         ));
```

Since you are getting the results from a query, you could also add `WHERE id != 2` to the query so it doesn't come back to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

here is one way, it depends on where you want to change it.  Right there in your  controller for example, like this

```
$output = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$output[] = $row;
}

$newValue = 2;

foreach($output as $key => $v){
    if($key === 'id'){
        $output[$key] =  $newValue;
    }

}

$json = json_encode(array(
"contacts" => $output
));
```